# How can I apply list of functions consecutively to a variable?

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply, purrr

I have a list of functions I want to apply to a string consecutively, changing the string.  For example, a list of regular expressions I want to remove from a string, e.g.

```
to_remove = c('a','b')
original = 'abcabd'
```

In this case, I could use a simple regular expression, e.g. 'a|b'.

```
library(stringr)
str_remove( original, paste0( to_remove, collapse='|'))
```

The actual situation is more complex than this, and the regular expression gets a little hairy. Also, I am curious how to do this in a proper R way.

Another way to phrase the question is, "How can I implement the following for loop using a vector approach?"

```
for( rem in to_remove) {
      original = str_remove( original, rem )
}
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringi` offers vectorized string replacement. The `replacement` argument can take on a vector of length 1, `""`, or a vector of the same length.

```
to_remove = c('a','b')
original = 'abcabd'

stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
    str = original,
    pattern = to_remove,
    replacement = "",
    vectorize_all = F
)
#> [1] "cd"
```

For repeated application of patterns, <s>perhaps use an alternative pattern</s>, per Stéphane's comment, `replace_all_*` with `vectorize = FALSE` is recursive, see for example the output of

```
stri_replace_all_regex(
    "abc", 
    pattern = c("^a", "^b"),
    replacement = "", 
    vectorise_all = FALSE
)
#> [1] "c"
```

Comment: With `vectorize_all=FALSE`, then `stri_replace_all_*` is recursive. Try e.g. `stri_replace_all_regex("abc", pattern = c("^a", "^b"), replacement = "", vectorise_all = FALSE)`. This removes `a` at the first position, then `b` at the first position.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You are right - thanks for the heads up, I have revised the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `str_remove_all` can take a list of inputs, but you can just use `str_replace_all` with a named vector to circumvent the issue:

```r
str_replace_all("abcdabcd", c("^a" = "",
                              "b" = "",
                              "c" = "",
                              "d$" = ""))

[1] "da"
```

This solution works with regular expressions as well. The `str_remove` functions are just an alias for `str_replace(x, "")`, so there is no loss in computational speed.

Alternatively, you can set the names of an empty vector as the regular expressions as such:

```r
to_remove <- c('a','b', )
empty <- rep("", length(to_remove))
names(empty) <- to_remove

str_replace_all("abcd", empty)
```

Or you can sequentially pipe the expression into a sequence of `str_remove` calls as so:

```r
"abcd" %>%
  str_remove_all("d$") %>%
  str_remove_all("a")
```